# If the MAC adress already exists, it keeps it, otherwise it will continue to run normally

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need that if the MAC address is already stored in the database, it does not save and continues to run the program, but if it does not have that MAC address it saves only that I do not know how to put it in an "IF":

```
if (macAddr != macAddr)
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter ee = new SqlDataAdapter("[dbo].[dbo.Bi_DispositivoInset]", ss);
                    ee.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    ee.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@disp_mac", SqlDbType.NVarChar, (17)).Value = macAddr;
                    ee.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@disp_nom", SqlDbType.VarChar,(50)).Value = nomeCompleto;
                    ee.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID_interno_cc", SqlDbType.Int).Value = "1";
                    ee.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    ss.Close();
                    
                     foreach (var s in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
                {
```

I know it's not like that but I'm new ...

Comment: Sounds like you want to query the database to see if a given `macAddr` exists first, use the existence result as a boolean, and conditionally INSERT a new `macAddr` if the query had no results.

Comment: Do you have a stored procedure that is basically the equivalent of `SELECT * FROM  [dbo].[dbo.Bi_DispositivoInset] WHERE macAddr == @macAddr`? You would want to use such a query to determine if a `macAddr` exists and conditionally insert a new one if not.

Comment: Does your object *really* have the schema name as a prefix? That is very confusing to look at, and I would suggest renaming it if so.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to approach this is with just a single round-trip.

You just want to insert a row only if it doesn't exist and then continue, so just have your procedure implement that, simply insert your data where it does `not exist`

```
create or alter procedure Bi_DispositivoInset
@disp_mac NVarChar (17)
@disp_nom VarChar (50)
@ID_interno_cc Int
as
...    
insert into [table] (disp_mac, disp_nom, ID_interno_cc)
select @disp_mac, @disp_nom, @ID_interno_cc
where not exists (select * from [table] where disp_mac=@disp_mac )
...
```